# React Native: What is the proper and correct .replace() logic for NavigationExperimental?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, reactjs

In React Native, currently I have the following for .push() and .pop() for NavigationExperimental:

```
case PUSH_ROUTE:
  if (state.routes[state.index].key === (action.route && action.route.key)) return state
return NavigationStateUtils.push(state, action.route)

case POP_ROUTE:
  if (state.index === 0 || state.routes.length === 1) return state
  return NavigationStateUtils.pop(state)
```

I tried searching but couldn't find the right logic to implement .replace(). What would be the proper and correct way to implement the logic for .replace()?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

NavigationStateUtils already have two replace functions. See the source code at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/NavigationExperimental/NavigationStateUtils.js

Comment: Which one would be the same as the `<Navigator/>'s` `navigator.replace()`? And what should the logic be?

Comment: just checking to see if you've read my previous comment. please let me know!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Navigator, so can't help you.